# Liberar memoria fuera de la función

Tags: c++

¿Se considera buenas prácticas liberar la memoria de un objeto desde una clase ajena?

Por ejemplo, en el constructor de Intro declaro los punteros de tres objectos y reservo memoria para estos, y para liberar la memoria reservada de los objetos mencionados, son liberados mediante el destructor de Node.

Por tanto, los punteros declarados en el constructor de Intro, una vez termine de ejecutarse el constructor, estos dejarán de existir, pero la memoria a la que apuntan continuará existiendo en memoria hasta que el destructor de Node se ejecute. ¿Es correcto?

Ejemplo:

```
void Node::addChild(Node *node)
{
    m_child.push_back(node);
}

Node::~Node()
{
    for(unsigned i=0; i<m_child.size() ;i++)
    {
        delete m_child[i];
    }
}

Intro::Intro()
{
    m_root = new Node;
    
    Shape *l_background = new Shape;
    Text *l_title = new Text;
    Text *l_author = new Text;

    m_root->addChild(l_background);
    m_root->addChild(l_title);
    m_root->addChild(l_author);
}
```

Comment: Si adquieres memoria dinamicamente y no la liberas ocurre lo que se llama `memory leaks` y quedará allí. Como perdiste el puntero a esa área de memoria no hay forma que el destructor se ejecute.

Comment: *"¿Se considera buenas prácticas liberar la memoria de un objeto desde una clase ajena?"*. No, lo correcto es que cada objeto sea el responsable de limpiar la memoria que asigna.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ¿Se considera buenas prácticas liberar la memoria de un objeto desde una clase ajena?

Esa no es la pregunta que debes hacerte. La pregunta es ¿Se considera buena práctica liberar memoria que no se dónde fue reservada? Y la respuesta es: No.

---

Se considera buena práctica que la memoria sea gestionada de una manera clara, concisa y fácil de rastrear, echemos un vistazo a la función que añade nodos:

```
void Node::addChild(Node *node)
{
    m_child.push_back(node);
}
```

Desde dentro de la función no hay manera de controlar lo que se recibe ni rastrear lo recibido hasta su origen, esto proporciona una interfaz que es más fácil de usar mal que de usar bien, observa:

```
Node n;
Node *x = new Node();
delete x;

// Compila, pero 0 no es un nodo válido.
n.addChild(0);
// Compila, pero nullptr no es un nodo válido.
n.addChild(nullptr);
// Compila, pero NULL no es un nodo válido.
n.addChild(NULL);
// Compila, pero 1 no es un nodo válido.
n.addChild(reinterpret_cast<Node *>(1));
// Compila, pero no creo que sea correcto que un nodo se guarde a si mismo
n.addChild(&n);
// Compila, pero x es un nodo borrado.
n.addChild(x);
```

Podrías ponerte a la defensiva y decir que tú jamás pasarías datos incorrectos a tu función, pero no olvidemos que en un entorno profesional tu código puede ser usado por varias personas que no tengan los mismos conocimientos que tu, si tu interfaz puede ser mal usada: será mal usada.